# Player not moving in Raylib

Tags: c++, game-development, raylib, game-programming

In Raylib I am trying to make a player character move however it is not moving

I have tried using different functions like KeyPressed(). Here is the code(This is compiled in c++20):

```
#include <raylib.h>;

int main(){
    int camX = 0;
    int camY = 0;
    InitWindow(1080, 720, "Arachnacide");
    while(!WindowShouldClose()){
        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_W)){
            camY -= 1;
        }
        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_S)){
            camY += 1;
        }
        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_A)){
            camX += 1;
        }
        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_D)){
            camX -= 1;
        }
        BeginDrawing();
        DrawCircle(540, 360, 25, RED);
        DrawCircle(camX, camY, 25, BLUE);
        EndDrawing();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to clear the background each time you draw.

```cpp
BeginDrawing();
ClearBackground(RAYWHITE); // Substitute with any color you prefer

...

EndDrawing();
```

Comment: Thank You so much, I thought I was going crazy!